# Compiling clank (Chrome for Android) from source gives error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to compile clank (now called Chrome for Android?) from a 268MB chrome_android.v18.0.1025123.tgz mentioned in here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq

I followed README.Chrome_for_Android_SourceDistribution in there and built Android from master on http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src (as of 7/31/2012).

Then I got to the part where I build clank itself with:

```
cd external/chrome && . build/android/envsetup.sh && clank_gyp && make -j16 libchromeview.so
```

At first I was missing some not-mentioned dependencies, which was easily fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgconf2-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libudev-dev
```

And now I'm seeing compilation errors like this:

```
 In file included from third_party/skia/include/core/SkTypes.h:15:0,
             from third_party/skia/include/core/SkTime.h:13,
             from third_party/skia/src/animator/SkTime.cpp:10:
 third_party/skia/include/core/SkPostConfig.h:145:27: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

I see stdio.h in many folders inside of android source.

How do I know which one to use? And why is the right one is not being used already?

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu12.04-amd64 and I want to compile clank for Nexus 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need additional dependencies and to ensure that your environment is set up to point towards the sdks, you might want to check this site out: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to these instructions. I was able to compile without Android SDK installed on that machine though.

Comment: Instead the build uses ndk and sdk in ~/android/master/prebuilt

Answer (score 2):

I found what was wrong. I used this to see more output from the build:

export V=1

This allowed me to notice that the following include directory is not correct:

```
-I/home/alex/android/master/prebuilt/ndk/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
```

It should be ".../prebuilds/...", not ".../prebuild/...":

```
-I/home/alex/android/master/prebuilts/ndk/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
```

I used an easy workaround for this:

```
ln -s /home/alex/android/master/prebuilts /home/alex/android/master/prebuilt
```

This allowed compiling a lot further.

There were two more issues I had to fix before being able to successfully compile, but they are not related to this question.