# How to get the source code of Chromium for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromium, android-browser

I'm trying to build Chromium open source browser for Android. I have referred:

Visit: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions

But, I think it will only build the test bundles not the full browser. Any idea how can I have it running on my device for making some changes to it through source code.

I checked out the code from Git as recommended and build it accordingly using depot_tools and targeting OS as android. All the build environment is correct and I can make "make -j4" command. But still eclipse source code is not available for me to make some changes.

How can I make change?

Please help me getting over this problem.

Comment: have you tried this? http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code#TOC-Android

Comment: Ya, tried this. Make changes in .gcleint as target OS as Android. But still. I'm not able to figure out that how can I make Chromium source code to work for me.

Comment: maybe this might help, but the first time when i built it i used single thread and not four threads. So just `make` command might help in getting a successful build, (assuming the build itself could be giving a problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build content shell alone using "make -j4 content_shell_apk" instead of building the full bundle.
This will give you content_shell.apk which can be installed on to any android device which runs 4.0 or higher.
If you want to make an eclipse project for content shell then you have to collect all necessary src files and resource files from chromium source tree.

```
src files:
base/android/java/src/org/chromium/*
media/base/android/java/src/org/chromium/*
ui/android/java/src/org/chromium/*
content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/*
content/shell/android/java/src/org/chromium/*
net/android/java/src/org/chromium/*

res files:
content/shell/android/res/*
pak file:
out/Release/content_shell/assets/*

native libs:
out/Release/content_shell/libs/armeabi-v7a/*
```

Comment: can you provide some steps to get the chromium project source code?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions -- full instruction for build chromium for android

Answer (score 1):

"At this time, a full compile does not build the browser. It only builds unit test bundles. As more code becomes available in the public Chromium source, more targets will be added."

Taken from the same page, i think here is your answer.

Comment: I saw that, but I was going through one thread which talks about "Clank" thing in the chromium for android.

See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765707/compiling-clank-chrome-for-android-from-source-gives-error-stdio-h-no-such-f

Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can definitely build a full browser as these [instructions](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions#TOC-Build-the-full-browser). You will have an apk file named "ChromePublic.apk". If you just want to test WebView, you can only build "WebView Shell" or "Content Shell" for your purpose.

Secondly, it's nearly impossible to import Chromium project to Eclipse IDE, because it's so complex for Eclipse can understand. You can edit the source code by Notepad++, then rebuild project as above instructions. If you just want to have "WebView Shell" project, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604150/embedded-chromium-or-webkit-in-android-app/33188306#33188306) maybe help you.