# Unable to resolved AIDL issue in Chromium Content Shell source code

Tags: android, eclipse, chromium, aidl, webviewchromium

I have complete build for Android Content shell from this link [AndroidBuildInstructions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions).

after that i want to make Eclipse project from it and i follow this link [code of Chromium for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104617/how-to-get-the-source-code-of-chromium-for-android).

But when i add all required java classes and required resource Only issue i am getting now is in Below two aidl file .

```
1)IRemoteAndroidKeyStoreInterface.aidl It is under Package org.chromium.net,Here is aidl file code:
// Copyright 2014 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

interface org.chomium.net.IRemoteAndroidKeyStore;
interface org.chromium.net.IRemoteAndroidKeyStoreCallbacks;

2)common.aidl  It is under Package org.chromium.content.common ,It's code is below 

// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// This file is needed to compile IChildProcessCallback.aidl and
// IChildProcessServices.aidl into java source files.  See
// content/public/android/java/content.xml for target aidl.

interface org.chromium.content.common.IChildProcessCallback;
interface org.chromium.content.common.IChildProcessService;
```

Both file give me Error like below one :

**Multiple markers at this line
- syntax error don't know what to do with ";"
- syntax error**

Do any one have complete code of ContentShell apk to make some modification in it as i am unable to make running code to Eclipse .Does any one have idea how to resolved this aidl issue for android content shell source code?

For just try i have remove that two aidl from both package and run project but it now give below Error:

```
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236): ContentView initialization failed.
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236): org.chromium.base.library_loader.ProcessInitException
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:190)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.ensureInitialized(LibraryLoader.java:85)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.ensureInitialized(LibraryLoader.java:57)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at org.chromium.content_shell_apk.ContentShellActivity.onCreate(ContentShellActivity.java:60)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:161)
04-08 15:22:56.362: E/ContentShellActivity(10236):  ... 17 more
```